# How to find whether IPs in subnet used for HSRP in softlayer API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We ordered a subnet on a private VLAN and when we try to use one of the IP. We realized that IP was used for HSRP on router/switches of Softlayer infrastructure. Is there any SL API to find out whether the IP is used for this purpose? We generally extract IP using softlayer python based client code like the below

ipinfo = network.ip_lookup()

and to determine whether it is used for any reserved purpose

ipinfo['isGateway'] is True or ipinfo['isBroadcast'] is True or ipinfo['isReserved'] is True

Really appreciate your inputs on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

IP Addresses reserved for HSRP have the property **isReserved** as True and in **note** property the text *“Reserved for HSRP.”*

You can use the method [SoftLayer_Network_Subnet::getIpAddresses](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet/getIpAddresses) with the following filter to get those IP Addresses:

```
            objectFilter={'ipAddresses':{'note':{'operation':'Reserved for HSRP.'}}}
```

Below you can see an example in python.

```
"""
Get Ip Addresses of a subnet which are reserved for HSRP protocol.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet/getIpAddresses
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress
https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-Masks
https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
from pprint import pprint as pp

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
API_USERNAME = 'set-me'
API_KEY = 'set-me'

# The id of subnet you wish to get information.
subnetId = 135840

# Object mask helps to get more and specific information
mask = 'id,ipAddress,isReserved,note'

# Use object-filter to get Ip Addresses reserved for HSRP
filter = {
            'ipAddresses': {
                'note': {'operation': 'Reserved for HSRP.'}
            }
        }

# Call SoftLayer API client
client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=API_USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

try:
    result = client['SoftLayer_Network_Subnet'].getIpAddresses(id=subnetId,
                                                               mask=mask,
                                                               filter=filter)
    pp(result)

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    pp('Unable to get the Ip Addresses %s, %s' % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

Links:

https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/articles/static-and-portable-ip-blocks 
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet/getIpAddresses 
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet

I hope this help you.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.